# ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package when trying to import models from another app in django

Tags: python, django

I have two django applications in my project in my project named electron: the first api and the second elec_meter. The directories are organized as follows:

```
electron /
   api/
      views.py
      ...
   elec_meter/
      models.py
      ...
```

In the api / views.py file I want to import elec_meter / models.py.This is how I do it:

```
from ..elec_meter.models import *
```

But I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

or

```
from electron.elec_meter.models import *
```

In this case I receive this error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'electron.elec_meter'
```

[Here is a picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIgpD.png)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `from elec_meter.models import *`

Comment: But please do not use `import *`. Mention *what* you import, importing all elements can have unexpected results, since it can override existing references.

Comment: Ok. It works but Pycharm considers this line to be an error.

Comment: then you have set the wrong directory as "Python root", click on the rigt button on the `electron` directory and marke it as the python root.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python root path is the `electron` directory, so you can not work with <s>`from electron.…`</s>.

You can import the objects by importing it starting with the name of the *app*, not the *project*. This thus means that you import this with:

```
from elec_meter.models import Model1, Model2
```

while you can make wildcard imports, it is often considered an antipattern, since it is unclear *what* you import. This means that it can set references to point to objects exported by the `elec_meter.models` module, and thus override the original references.